# C language to MIPS. Fibonacci Number

Tags: c, assembly, mips, cpu, cpu-registers

I was trying to convert this piece of code into MIPS instruction. Lets say that a is in $a0, b is in $a1, n is in $a2, the result is in $v0, and to end the
program, call “jr $ra” to return to the subroutine caller

```
int fib_iter(int a, int b, int n) {
 if (n == 0)
     return b;
 else
     return fib_iter(a+b, a, n-1);
```

For the simplicity, we just ignore the stack frame for this one
And this is the MIPS code I converted:

```
bne $a1, $zero, ELISEIF // if b != 0 go to ELSEIF
lw $v0, $0($a1) // load b to result if n == 0
j DONE // done
ELSEIF:
lw $at, $0($a0) // temp = a
add $a0, $a0, $a1 // a = a + b
add $a1, $zero, $zero // clear b
lw $a1, $0($at) // b = a
sub $a2, $a2, $1 // n = n - 1
jr $ra // call the subroutine caller
Done:
what to put??
```

Please point out my errors(there might be a a lot since I am new to this)

Thanks for your time for helping me and I appreciate that

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It's a job for a compiler.

Comment: @n.m.: It's probably a course exercise to give the students some basic understanding of how to implement a given algorithm in MIPS assembly.

Comment: @n.m. yea it is a course exercise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lw $v0 $0($a1)` will do  `$v0 = $a1[0]` instead of `$v0 = $a1`. To do the latter, use `mv $v0 $a1`.

Also `$at` is reserved for [pseudoinstructions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Pseudoinstructions) in MIPS. I means they get modified by pseudoinstructions. So, do not use it unless you are sure that you have not used any pseudoinstruction. `$t1 to $t7` are temporary registers. Use any one of them.

Here is the correct code

```
FIB:
    bne $a2, $zero, ELSE // if n != 0 go to ELSE
    mv $v0, $a1 // load b to result if n == 0
    jr $ra // end of recursion, so call the subroutine caller
ELSE:
    mv $t0, $a0 // temp = a
    add $a0, $a0, $a1 // a = a + b
    mv $a1, $t0 // b = a
    addi $a2, $a2, -1 // n = n - 1
    j FIB // call FIB recursively
```

Comment: `bne $a1, $zero, ELSE` should be `bne $a2, $zero, ELSE`. `add $a1, $zero, $zero` should be removed. `sub $a2, $a2, $1` should be `addi $a2, $a2, -1`.